# Need to generate divisible numbers between two integers

Tags: java

Like the title says, I'm trying to write a program that takes two numbers and finds what is divisible by another number. For example: I enter x as my first integer and y as my last. Then I ask the program to find everything between those two numbers divisble by z. so if I say numbers between 1 and 10 divisible by 2. so it would output 2,4,6,8 and not include 10. This is what I have so far

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Please enter two integers seperated by space(s):  ");     

int num1 = kb.nextInt();
int num2 = kb.nextInt();

System.out.print("\nPlease enter the integer your output should be divisible by:  ");   

int divisor = kb.nextInt(); //asking for the divisor

for (int i =num1+1; i<num2; i++)
{
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the numbers are divisible by the integer and print only divisible numbers.

```
for (int i=num1+1; i<num2; i++)
{
    if(divisor != 0 && i % divisor == 0) // add this
        System.out.println(i);
}
```